# Anchor link scrolling navigation not scrolling to the section since sticky content

Tags: html, css

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto active" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
         <ul>
<nav>
```

Below sections are sticky content

```
 <section id="partners" />
 <section id="partners" />
 <section id="services" />
 <section id="contact" />
```

If i  try to navigate using anchor tab after i reached at the bottom,Its not navigating.How we can resolve this issue

[Sample project](https://codepen.io/KhaledPen/pen/YzXeXLm)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] so that we can follow along.

Comment: The currently linked codepen looks to be for a different issue?

Comment: @CBroe Thats the root cause

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. What you have currently linked, does not show any anchors to jump to different sections anywhere, as far as I can tell. And the code you have shown above, does not appear to be contained in it either. Very unclear what the actual problem is supposed to be here now.